# Swift extension for getting instance private property

Tags: swift, abaddressbook, swift-extensions

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook) open source library which is a wrapper on AddressBook.framework. There's no method for deleting contact, so I'm gonna use default `ABAddressBookRemoveRecord`. However for that I need the `ABAddressBookRef`.

Since it's declared in `APAddressBook.m` file of that `APAddressBook` library as 
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;` and I'm not able to get access to it, I wanted to write extension in Swift, containing method returning it.

So this is body of my extension:

```
extension APAddressBook {
    private struct AssociatedKey {
        static var addressBookRef = "addressBook"
    }

    var xo: ABAddressBook! {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.addressBookRef)
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.addressBookRef, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
        }
    }

    func getABAddressBook() -> ABAddressBookRef {
        return self.xo
    }

}
```

I've also tried using `private var xoAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0` as associatedKey, but calling `getABAddressBook()` function always crashes with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.`

What's wrong with my code? Also is there better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe it's not particulary an answer to your questions but here is some thoughts.

You only know what to pass in `obc_objc_getAssociatedObject` because your lib is open source.

So why wouldnt you use that to fit it under your needs?

If i were you I'd just move that property to the public access. I dont find it a really worse solution than trying to access private property via `obc_` methods.

Regarding your question did you try to specify addressBookRef as `: NSString`? Since Apple now made swift's String and NSString two different types.

Comment: Hi, you mean directly edit library? I surely thought about it after few hours :D but from long term perspective it's not the best solution, I'd have to do it every time they update library... that's why we have categories/extensions for I think.

I don't get that String part... what does it have to do with addressBookRef?